# Xcode submit the app to the store

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to submit my app to the AppStore but when i do it an error message appear with this:

> ERROR ITMS-90329 your package contains a file 'Myapp .app/Myapp' with
>   a name that contains leading or trailing whitespace

How can i solve this problem? (i already changed the product name, bundle name, bundle display name, project name)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Comment: your app name contain the white space i think you should remove first `Myapp.app/Myapp'` like this . update your product name.

Comment: ok but from where i can modify Myapp .app/Myapp to Myapp.app/Myapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go Info.plist and change **Product Name** "Myapp " to "Myapp".

Comment: I'm glad that you fix kazui :)

Comment: dear @kazui, you should also click check mark at left side of my answer "if you think this is the one which  solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to build settings of targets in Xcode and select the **Packaging** section and check the **Product Name** its can contains **leading or trailing whitespace**.